# What is the possible use case for @Transactional(NEVER)

Tags: java, jpa

Docs state obvious thing:
a method will throw an exception if it is executed inside existent transaction.

Can anyone give a meaningful example of when/why it can be used on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there may be several use cases that require your code not to run in a transaction. You'd use NEVER to enforce that as opposed to NOT_SUPPORTED which would just "suspend" the current transaction and resume it afterwards.

One use case that we had would be sending an email after some transactional operation. Sending the email itself doesn't require a transaction and to make sure the operation was successful and didn't get rolled back at the last moment our email sending service uses NEVER (otherwise we might accidentally send a "success" email and then get a rollback). That way if someone would call it while the operation's transaction still hasn't been successfully committed yet we'd get an exception and know that this should be fixed.

Comment: this is a good example but am I right that it is useful only when caller of  `sendEmail()` is not sure whether he is inside tx scope or not?

Comment: @fyrkov yes it's meant to make sure the call doesn't happen inside a tx scope. Often you'd use NEVER (or MANDATORY for the opposite) in "library" code (might just be internal) that might be called from other places eventually - since you don't know what other callers are doing you want to make sure those calls fail fast if the setup isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

One use case might be framework related code that handles transactions or scopes. Think of Apache Deltaspike, arquillian, hibernate, ...

If you expose public methods you might want to make sure they are not wrongly used inside some transaction. Instead of unintentionally messing up open transactions you would rather fail-fast using @NEVER.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a nontransactional resource inside your code and want to make sure that others know this fact, you can use this feature.

Comment: Just pasting an image of [some copyrighted material](https://www.manning.com/books/ejb-3-in-action-second-edition) that you don't own is not an answer.

Comment: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/284827)